# Why can't I have a referential constraint with a one to zero-to-one association?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm using entity framework 4.3 model first and can't figure out why I'm not allowed to have a one to zero-to-one association along with a referential constraint.

I have two main problems.  I can't force referential integrity (without manual intervention) and my lazy loading doesn't seem to work... all my 1 to many associations are fine.

I basically have two tables, Loans and Contracts.  The Contracts table has a scalar field for LoanId.

Until a loan is *submitted*, it does not have contract data and I chose not to place everything in the same table due to the size of the contract data.  Ie. I don't want contract data retrieved from the database unless it is actually required.

I've searched around and can't seem to find any model first information that clearly answers my questions.  Any information that may help me understand and clarify my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Craig

Answer (score 2):

I guess `LoanId` field is not a primary key in Contracts table. In such case you cannot have such one-to-one relation because EF doesn't support it. When you create `LoanId` field in `Contracts` table the only way to force one-to-one relation is to add unique constraint on that field. EF currently doesn't support unique keys (except primary keys) so the only way to create one-to-one relation is to create relation between primary keys (`Loan.Id` <-> `Contract.Id`). If you don't follow this you will get error in designer.

Comment: Ahhh... Now I understand the error.  This little piece of info resolves a lot of my confusion.  I'm a little disappointed I can't structure my underlying database they way I've always done it, but I'll get over it.

Many thanks!

Comment: @Kraeg If this answered your question, click the check mark on the underneath the up/down arrows, please!